# How can I get rid of a blind Cave Troll?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a blind Cave Troll unconscious in the center of my fort. This has brought the entire place to a stand still because every dwarf is too terrified of it to do anything. I have a full military of 10 dwarves set to kill it but it looks like it might be healing faster than they can kill it. These are extremely under qualified dwarfs. I can't use my workshops to build anything to help. What can I do to get rid of the damn thing?

I'm playing on v34.

Comment: If your military is chopping away at it, I suspect eventually they'll manage to kill it.  Until then, your squad is getting fantastic troll anatomy training!

Comment: Update: The ogre (oops, not a troll, an ogre) is dead! It took out 7 of my 10 military members with it, but that's how the cookie crumbles. Going to be quite a feat to get everything back in order but at least my fort can go back to normal operation. Thanks all!

Comment: Another update: While my entire military was fighting with and dying to the ogre, the fort was overrun by Elk Birds. Nothing to be done now, entire military is wiped. Starting a new fort with defenses as a top priority!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep your military at it. While they pummel at the troll, they gain experience in their applicable combat skills, which makes them more efficient. It's just a matter of time until they will be experienced enough to out-damage its healing powers.

You can speed up the process by giving them better weapons. But maybe you shouldn't, because they currently gain experience much more efficiently than they could through training. This prolonged beatup session will certainly pay off in the future when you need them to defend against another threat.

Comment: Thanks, will do! Mostly worried about potential for starvation. Nobody can eat because of the darn thing. I have a safety backup save in case things get hairy. Thanks again!

Comment: @JulianJocque That might indeed be a problem, but none you can't solve by designating a second dining room somewhere else and deactivating your squads once in a while which will turn them back into civilians, abandon the battle and take a snack.

Comment: @Phillipp I was actually talking about the civilians. I built my fort in an unfortunately centralized way so I have bedrooms, dining hall and workshops all on one Z level. 90% of the civilians are cowering in the corner, unable to eat or do anything else while the beast stands in the middle of the place, grinding the entire fort to a halt.

Comment: @JulianJocque You could free them by recruiting your miner as a soldier, order him to move away from the battle and have him dig an escape tunnel on a z-level below or above to the civilians so he gives them a chance to escape.

Comment: For historic reference I believe a burrow will override the fear as long as it's not too close to the cause of the issue.